# PHP Configuration : PDO extension is enabled but not loading

Tags: php, apache, magento, wamp

I'm using Windows 7, wamp server version 2.2, PHP version 5.2.9. When I try to run my magento websites on a localhost it gives me the following error:

"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded"

I have double check that PDO extensions are enabled in the php.ini file.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_msql.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Also the phpinfo loading the right php.ini file. It was working earlier but suddenly start to give the error. I also checked the Apche error log but didn't find any clue.

Please suggest.

Comment: Does phpinfo() list the PDO extension?

Comment: Does php extension directory has relevant extension .dll files?

Comment: This is a Zend Framework error, not related with Magento! It's throwing "Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception" message which is checking the PDO extension availability. Also, make sure which version of PHP using, threaded or non-threaded!

Comment: @Botond : The phpinfo is not listing the PDO extension.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: The following path is given in the php.ini  
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.9-2/ext/"  I have checked the folder and dlls are placed there.

Comment: When I switched to PHP version 5.3.10 from 5.2.9 using PHP add on, it started to load the PDO extension but getting connection reset error on magento sites. It was working recently for 5.2.9 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First move the extension directory to \Windows\System32\inetsrv{php}\extension
- Change the path from php.ini file

I think you have a security problem to loading .dll! Try this and let me know the result.

---

To find out which php.ini file has been loaded, try the following ( run in commandline and webserver to make sure which edition loading different environment).

**Checking the php.ini file path :**

```
<?php
    $path = php_ini_loaded_file();
    echo 'The loaded file path is :' . $path;
?>
```

Comment: I have moved the extensions to the following directory:  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\php5.2.9-2\ext  and changed the path in php.ini but still its not working.

Comment: @MubashirQayyum haw many php.ini file available in the Wamp server? Just try the code above in my answer. Check and let me know.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir your feedback is much appreciated. I've run your code and get this : "The loaded file path is :E:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini" and I'm sure that I have changed the path in this particular php.ini file.

Comment: @MubashirQayyum dear brother, we have a left thing which is might be corrupted .dll or misconfiguration. My suggestion is use to Zend Server Community edition instead of WAMP, better than nothing!

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Thanks brother! you are right. The dlls were corrupted. I have reinstalled the wamp server. Again, thanks a lot.